# How to wrap text to the next line in curses?

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

I am trying to display text files in the terminal using curses, but some lines of the file are larger than the size of my terminal. How can I wrap this overflowing text to the next line?

```
    def display(self):
        max_y, max_x = self.stdscr.getmaxyx()

        text_list = self.text.split("\n")

        for y in range(len(text_list)): 
            for x in range(len(text_list[y])):
                self.stdscr.addstr(y, x, text_list[y][x])
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest taking look at [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) (it is part of standard library). Consider following example

```
import textwrap
text = '''This is first paragraph
This is second paragraph which is also longest
This is last paragraph'''
paras = text.splitlines()
lines = [j for i in paras for j in textwrap.wrap(i,width=25)]
print(lines)
```

output

```
['This is first paragraph', 'This is second paragraph', 'which is also longest', 'This is last paragraph']
```

Note: I used 25 as width for illustration purposes. I used nested comprehension to get flat list, as using `textwrap.wrap` on elements of list gives nested list (`list` of `list`s), you might elect other way to flatten such list.

Comment: Thank you, while this works, it treats multiple \n characters no differently from a single \n. So "hi\n\nhello" becomes `["hi", "hello"]` while i need it to be `["hi", "", "hello"]`